# Unable to execute bash script through cron/crontab

Tags: bash

I have the below cmd in `extract.sh` .

It works when execute in terminal to search for "ABC123" in `orig.txt` and output to `result.txt` the remaining content after "ABC123" is found.

Unfortunately when I run the script via cron/crontab, it seem to ignore/skip the "more" command and just output orig.txt to result.txt.

Any help is appreciated.

---------------------extract.sh-----------------------------------------

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
. $HOME/.profile
more +/"ABC123" orig.txt > result.txt
```

---

----------------------crontab-------------------------------------------

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * * /root/extractpdf_v3.sh
* * * * * /bin/bash /root/extract.sh
```

---

Comment: What, exactly, do you expect the `more` command to do when it’s running under ``cron``? And what, exactly, *does* it do?

Comment: I need to find "ABC123" string inside orig.txt, and extract the remaining content after it (I don't want the content before "ABC123"). more command does the trick.

Comment: Would you please provide full path for `orig.txt` like `more +/"ABC123" /path/to/orig.txt > /path/to/result.txt` and once escape the plusSlash `\+\/` sign there

Comment: @vd2gl Thanks for reminding me of the (non-standard?) `+` option to `more`, but please note that `more` is still meant as an interactive viewer. Anyhow, did you try with pull paths of the files given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` instead of `more`, as you mention in you comment you need the content of the file after the line that match specific word.
For example input file:

```
Test before
Test match
Test after
```

command:

```
sed -n -e '/match/,$p'
```

output:

```
Test match
Test after
```

- `-n` disables default behaviour of sed of printing each line after executing its script on it,
- `-e` indicated a script to sed,
- `/match/,$` is an address (line) range selection meaning the first
  line matching the 'match' regular expression (like grep) to the end
  of the file ($)
- `p` is the print command which prints the current line.

For more details, the original answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103531/how-to-get-the-part-of-file-after-the-line-that-matches-grep-expression-first

Comment: Many thanks, will try it out & update. But any idea why more me is not working for cron?

Comment: @vd2gl I don't have very clear answer, but the issue is not with cron even without cron try `more +/"ABC123" orig.txt > result.txt` it won't work, you will get all the file content in the result.txt file, I'm not sure but more is a command to view (but not modify) the contents of a text file one screen at a time.

Comment: @vd2gl you are using it to process the content and getting new content and save it to a file

Comment: Hi Wissam, your cmd is working. I have check through your link for more example as well. What if i am trying to match a string with space/symbol? I attempted the below, but am getting error.


---------------------------------extract---------------------------------------

matchtext="Content-Type:"
sed -n -e "/$matchtext/,\$p" orig.txt > final.txt

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: @vd2gl you can by using escape character like \$ to match $ and you can use regex too between `\...\`

Comment: Oh i somewhat get what you mean. many thanks, its working.

Comment: @vd2gl no worries, can you select the answer please if it's the answer you need, so it will not stay as unanswered

Comment: Test before
Test match
Test after
Test end

What i i want to match and start "Test match" and end at "Test after"?

Comment: Now you could start reading the `sed` manual! Before the comma is the starting line, after the comma the ending line. The ending line is currently `$`, which stands for the last line. If you want to end at a given pattern, replace `$` with `/end pattern/`.